# Get number of occurrences spread out over columns of the same row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to get the number of pregnancies for x number of times.

| name | baby_dob1 | baby_dob2 | baby_dob3 | Pregnant |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | 20-01-2021 | 02-03-2022 |  | True |
| Esther | 10-01-2020 |  |  | True |
| Helen | 01-01-2020 | 02-02-2021 | 09-09-2023 | False |
| Laura |  |  |  | True |
| Queen | 25-04-2020 | 22-04-2022 | 18-07-2022 | False |

The output should look like this:

| Category of pregnancies | Number of women |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |

Meaning:
3 women have been pregnant three times.
1 woman has had two pregnancies.
1 woman has had one pregnancy.

Logic:

You can only be pregnant three times on the system.

`baby_dob1` is the date of birth of the first baby.
`baby_dob2` is the date of birth of the second baby.
`baby_dob3` is the date of birth of the third and last baby.

`pregnant` column means that the mother is currently pregnant for another baby which is yet to be delivered.

Examples:

Helen has had three pregnancies.
Laura is currently pregnant so she has one pregnancy.
Mary would count as three pregnancies. Two that are in the past and one that is currently ongoing since the `pregnant` column is `true`.

How can I write the Postgres query?

Comment: Is the table seriously laid out that way?  So what happen if you have more than 3 babies???

Comment: Have you even tried anything???

Comment: Advice: Change your data model to a 3NF model. In that case you would have one single record for each baby, and linking these records to the right mother. That also solves the issue counting babies per mother. And this would be just the first problem this new/better model solves.

Comment: It should be noted that the assumption that pregnancy results in the birth of a baby is insensitive: Pregnancies that fail, either naturally or by intervention, are common. The number of pregnancies does **not** necessarily equal the number of births.

Comment: @Bohemian: In fairness, the OP does want the *"number of pregnancies"*. Then again, there is nothing in the table that would account for aborted pregnancies ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can only be pregnant three times on the system.

If that's actually how the system is supposed to work, then the table definition is fine. Else, consider normalizing your relational design as suggested in comments to work with a variable number of babies (and pregnancies).

With [`num_nonnulls()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-FUNC-TABLE) and [`NULLIF()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF)

```sql
SELECT num_nonnulls(baby_dob1, baby_dob2, baby_dob3, NULLIF(pregnant, false)) AS "number of pregnancies"
     , count(*) AS "number of women"
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Other variants:

```sql
SELECT num_nonnulls(baby_dob1, baby_dob2, baby_dob3)
     + pregnant::int AS "number of pregnancies"
     , count(*) AS "number of women"
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

```sql
SELECT (baby_dob1 IS NOT NULL)::int
     + (baby_dob2 IS NOT NULL)::int
     + (baby_dob3 IS NOT NULL)::int
     + pregnant::int AS "number of pregnancies"
     , count(*) AS "number of women"
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WRLcu8mS)

2nd and 3rd variants use the fact that the cast `true::int` yields `1`. Both also assume the column `pregnant` to be defined `NOT NULL`.

The 1st variant doesn't need either of these tricks / assumptions. Hence, my favorite.

Aside:
Always work with ISO date literals. "2021-01-20", not "20-01-2021". ISO literals are unambiguous with any `datestyle` setting - as opposed to other formats.